# incorrect output for multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

why is it that sometimes I get the output:

Patient-4 visits doctor office.

Patient-2 visits doctor office.

Patient-1 visits doctor office.

When I am expecting the output in increasing order, i.e patient 1, then patient 2 or 3, then patient 4 or 5. i.e I can't understand how it can see print 4 before it even got to 0 since the initial for loop in the main class is what sets the patient number, and I instantly start the thread.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    NUM_P = 5;//TEMPORARILY HARD CODE, WILL TAKE ARG FROM COMMANDLINE IN THE FUTURE
    NUM_A = 2;
    Patient[] myPatients = new Patient[NUM_P];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_P; i++)
    {
         Patient patient = new Patient();
         patient.setPatientNumber(i);
         myPatients[i] = patient;
         myPatients[i].start();
    }
}
```

In the patient class,

```
public void run() 
{
    attendParty();
    visitDoctor();
}

public void visitDoctor()
{
    System.out.println("Patient-"+(this.getPatientNumber())+" visits doctor office.");
}

public void attendParty() throws InterruptedException
{
    Random randomGen = new Random();
    int val = randomGen.nextInt(101);
    if (val < 20)
    {
        interrupt();
        //NO NEED TO CREATE A PATIENT THREAD, THE PATIENT IS NOT SICK HEHE
    }
    else
    {
        this.setSickness(true);//He is sick
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you patients have a communication with other patients or the doctor or some scheduler? If not, they can make others starve.

Comment: If you want sequential execution then use a single thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you start a thread, it's totally up to the VM as to when that thread gets cycles. There is no guarantee that they will run in the order they are start()ed.

Comment: So it is not sequential? How can that possibly be so?

Comment: @Ozymandias A thread has a set of commands that get executed in a specific order. The OS gives time share to different threads however it feels best. By putting commands on multiple threads, you remove any assurance as to the order they'll be executed in.

Answer (score 1):

When threads run in parallel, order of execution is generally undefined. So your code's output is perfectly normal - you start all threads almost at the same time, and most of the time they run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Threadhandling is done by the vm not your code. Meaning your system decides when and how long a thread is allowed to run, unless you command a thread to wait, sleep or yield. There is also the option to declare preferences.
Those switches do not wait untill the thread reaches a semicolon and can (mostly do) happen between opperations on bytecode level. Generally it is not advised to not interfere with threadhandling from within the code, unless you absolutely need it for timing purposes.
Still you should allways remeber [syncronisation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) whenever there is the possibility that two threads access and change the same resource so that switching threads in the middle of an opperation/method/ect. would mess up the results for both threads.